# Build a dynamic UI for HDFS with REST API

Tags: python, rest, hadoop, hdfs, webhdfs

For scientific purposes we have to build a UI for a Hadoop Data Lake.

I found out that Hadoop offers a REST API for the WebHDFS. Unfortunately, the standard WebHDFS is not usable for the enduser.

I would like to use the Hadoop REST API to program a dynamic web file browser as well as Hue.

Unfortunately, I can not take this to Hue because we only need the file browser from Hue and not the whole system.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you want Hue, then just use it and update the html to hide everything but the file browser

For example https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hdfs-filebrowser

Otherwise, yes, it's possible to rewrite all the WebHDFS calls into your own application